# How to make a sound only once when you hover over a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, hover, mouseover

I have a few divs that have a classname "soundWhenHover".
I want to play an audio (a click sound) whenever I hover over it. I can achieve this by iterating over the elements with the class name and adding an event listener for mouseover. However, if you move the mouse around the div, it makes the sound more than once. I only want the audio to play once every time you hover over the div.
I added a boolean that changes to true once it hovers over, then on mouseout it changes it to false. The problem with this is that the div has children elements, and when you hover over those elements it counts as a mouseout. How do I make a sound once for the div *and* the elements?

Comment: just bind your sound to the mouseenter event of the parent element.

Comment: XD I didn't even think of mouseenter. Thanks
Edit: tried it and it works thanks so much!

Comment: no problem. I added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just bind your sound to the mouseenter event of the parent element:

```js
const mouseTarget = document.getElementById('mouseTarget');

mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  console.log('play sound');
});
```

```css
#mouseTarget, #child {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

#mouseTarget {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}


#child {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseTarget">
 <div id="child">
  Test
 </div>
</div>
```